# Android GridView selection on non focusable element

Tags: android, gridview

I have grid view, and base adapter.
I always have 12 elements in adapter, but sometimes there need to be non focusable or invisible elements.

If I have one visible element, and press right, non visible item is selected.
I need somehow to disable focus from that element in grid.

I tried to use

```
 @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {

        Log.d("ARE ALL ITEMS", "ENTERED");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

        if (position >= numberOFRealElement) {
            Log.d("FAVORITE DISABLED", "ENTERED");
            return false;
        }

        Log.d("FAVORITE ENABLED", "ENTERED");
        return true;
    }
```

But no success. How to call those methods? It seems that they are not called automatically.

Edit:
Hidding element code:

```
        item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        item.setFocusable(false);
        item.setEnabled(false);
        item.setClickable(false);


        return item;
```

Comment: How are you making your items INVISIBLE?

Comment: Tried everything...I setEnable(false) setClicable(false) setFocusable(false) setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) on layout that I'm returning in getView and on all child views in that layout...but that's not work. Overriden methods in base adapter are non called at all.

Comment: When I move right, there is no selector, couse i've removed it...but focus is still there somewhere. When i go left...selector is visible on visible element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't success to simply solve this problem, so I had to find workaround for this Android bug.
I had to attach OnKeyListener on GridView and detect what is the selected position. If user clicks right or down and there are invisible element, I return true in KeyListener, and Android don't respond to that key. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

When you make your view `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, its only invisible, but it still holds the place in UI, but when you use `GONE`, the view gets invisible and also it does not use any space in UI.

So in your case, when it becomes `GONE`, it wont be able to take any focus or it cannot get selected.

Comment: Nope. The same thing happens :/